# AngularJS - How to get object on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects. I displayed the names in input fields. Now I want the updated object (whatever user fills in input field) on button click

Example if I enter **“abcde” and “pq”** in input field it should show update object on button click

```
[
    {
      name:'abcde’
    },
    {
      name:'pq'
    }
    ];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/51BlTe5tAEgMV7ZlJLKV

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.c = [
    {
      name:'abc'
    },
    {
      name:'pqr'
    }
    ];

    $scope.onclick =function(){

      alert('dd')
      console.log($scope.c)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-model` in your template

```
<li ng-repeat="x in c">
  <input type="text" ng-model='x.name' value="{{x.name==='abc'?'ddd':'hhh'}}"/>
</li>
```

If you need to update `$scope.c` on button click, use `ng-model` on a different scope variable and assign the same to `$scope.c` in `onclick`

UPDATE:

Also note that ng-model does not depend on `value`, so `x.name==='abc'?'ddd':'hhh'` should be done in the `onclick` or `ng-change` event handler

Comment: cn you share plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this out.

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in displayValue">
      <input type="text" ng-model='x.name' ng-change='valueChanged(x.name,$index)'/>
 </li>
```

And in your controller you can have 2 different json one is for display purpose and one for actual values. So conditionally showing "hhhh" and "dddd" will also be satisfy.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.displayValue = [
    {
      name:'abc' == 'abc'? 'hhhh' : 'dddd'
    },
    {
      name:'pqr' == 'abc'? 'hhhh' : 'dddd'
    }
    ];

  $scope.actualValue = [
    {
      name: ''
    },
    {
      name:''
    }
    ];

    $scope.valueChanged =function(value,index)
    {
      $scope.actualValue[index].name =  value;
    }

    $scope.onclick =function(){

      console.log($scope.actualValue)
    }

});
```